# When I try to bake my texture, the image doesn't come out correctly

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, unreal-engine

I'm new to blender so I'm just starting to learn the functions of this software. I'm trying to import my model into unreal and all my textures are procedural. I first attempted to bake using *diffuse* but the image came out black. I then tried using *glossy* but the textures were white instead. I then tried *combined* which got the colors but came out darker than expected.

Does anyone know how I can bake my texture to be more lighter so I can import it correctly to Unreal?

Here's my Material Properties
[image: Material Property]

My combined baked texture
[image: Baked Texture]

And my model
[image]

Comment: What do your bake options look like? Firstly, don't use combined. For the diffuse (basecolor), both types of lighting (direct and indirect) should be unchecked, and color should be checked. Use Roughness bake type for roughness. It looks like your material is metallic, so that map should be pure white. For the Normal, use Normal bake type - make sure 32-bit float is enabled.

Comment: the 'diffuse color' for metal is black. If you try to bake something with a *Metallic* value greater than 0.0 the result will become very dark/black. Subsurface Scattering behaves in a similar way. Set  to 0.0 before the bake and reset the value after the bake. If your model has metallic parts then you can bake a *Metallic* mask (black & white image, 1=white=metallic) to define where you want to have metal and where not.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. here's an image of my bake options. https://i.imgur.com/MXb5Mm6.png